# How to stream all records from Cassandra?

Tags: scala, cassandra, akka

I need to stream all records from Cassandra. Currently I am using `akka-persistence-cassandra` to stream the data:

```
val querier =
        PersistenceQuery(system)
          .readJournalFor[CassandraReadJournal](CassandraReadJournal.Identifier)
      
      val selectDistinctPersistenceIds = new SimpleStatement(
      "SELECT DISTINCT persistence_id, partition_nr FROM messages")
        .setFetchSize(100000)

        querier.session.select(selectDistinctPersistenceIds).map { row =>
          val id = row.getString(0)
          id
        }
```

This works fine when the number of records are around 1.5 million. But when the number of records exceeds > 1.5 million records, then I get `read timeout` error.

I am using:

```
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-persistence-cassandra" % "0.58"
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-persistence" % "2.6.12"
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-persistence-query" % "2.6.12"
```

Edit:
Error Logs:

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.OperationTimedOutException: [/<ip-address>:9042] Timed out waiting for server response", exceptionStackTrace="java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.OperationTimedOutException: [/<ip-address>:9042] Timed out waiting for server response
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:552)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:513)
    at akka.persistence.cassandra.package$ListenableFutureConverter$$anon$2.$anonfun$run$2(package.scala:25)
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by setting a higher value for `cassandra-journal.socket.read-timeout-millis` than the default value of 12000ms.

```
cassandra-journal {
  ...

  socket {
    # the per-host read timeout in milliseconds. Should be higher than the timeout settings
    # used on the Cassandra side.
    read-timeout-millis = 30000
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Issue is with your driver session out setting tune it according your need.

May be issue with **gap-timeout**
or increase no of retries. and **timeout** setting .

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change any setting, as I am not sure how much data is there in Cassandra.

Comment: Do you have logs present with you. what is the error it will give some clue else it is not possible to debug the problem

Comment: "I am not sure how much data is there in Cassandra." That's really something you should know before attempting to stream it all out. @himanshuIIITian

Comment: For an estimate, the above code fails for ~8M records. Hence the data is >8M records.

Comment: @sandeeprawat - added error logs in the question.

Comment: here it is clearly telling OperationTimedOutException so  u have to increase the time out setting

Comment: How can I increase the timeout setting just for the query mentioned in the question?

Comment: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-persistence-cassandra/current/configuration.html